# Typing with JSDoc3 an immutable object that uses generic keys is not well recognized in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I need help for typing with JSDoc3 an Immutable Object with generic keys because WebStorm is always complaining.
Maybe I am wrong, please tell me.

Basically, typing an object with generic keys can be written as bellow

```
/** @typedef {Object<string,number>} myObject */
```

My object is Immutable, so I have created more JSDoc to cover some Immutable functions:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ImmutableObject
 * @property {function} set
 * @property {function} setIn 
 */
```

Also my keys are in an enum, so more JSDoc

```
/**
 * @enum
 */
const SOME_KEYS= {KEY1: 'key1', KEY2:'key2'}
```

Then I put all together:

```
/** @typedef {ImmutableObject<SOME_KEYS,number>} myImmutableObject */
```

Despite all my efforts, WebStorm always complains that the function does not exists when I use an immutable function declared on an object type with `myImmutableObject`!

Here is a screenshot made from WebStorm 2020 (same on 2019):

[image: screenshot made from WebStorm 2020]

However, `ImutableObject` type work well when used "alone", here is a screenshot made from WebStorm 2020:

[image: screenshot made from WebStorm 2020]

Answer (score 0):

Extending typedefs is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-34403](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34403) and linked tickets for updates